# Invalid data length for AES

Tags: dart

I try to run example from https://pub.dev/packages/aes_crypt

```
Uint8List key = Uint8List.fromList(
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
  Uint8List iv = Uint8List.fromList(
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);

  var crypt = AesCrypt('my cool password');
  crypt.aesSetParams(key, iv, AesMode.cbc);

  Uint8List srcData = Uint8List.fromList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  Uint8List encryptedData = crypt.aesEncrypt(srcData); // error on this line
  Uint8List decryptedData = crypt.aesDecrypt(encryptedData);
```

but there is the error

```
Invalid argument(s): Invalid data length for AES: 5 bytes.
#0      _Aes.aesEncrypt (package:aes_crypt/src/aes.dart:244:7)
#1      AesCrypt.aesEncrypt (package:aes_crypt/src/aescrypt.dart:370:48)
#2      main (package:aestest/aes.dart:36:35)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Comment: The error are throw because you input cannot be split into blocks of 16 bytes: https://github.com/alexgoussev/aes_crypt/blob/68cb8f74705d46f060d30b237dd19f4b7170a763/lib/src/aes.dart#L244 . AES works on blocks of 16 bytes which you can read about here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/52114

Comment: I will recommend reading about some of the methods in the API since some of them can be used for arbitrary length of data: https://pub.dev/documentation/aes_crypt/latest/aes_crypt/AesCrypt-class.html#instance-methods